# Merging the results of two sql queries in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to implement a search function that not only search in one table (tasks) but also in another related table (activities). Activities has a column name task that identifies the task it belongs to (which is the column keyid in the tasks table). The way I search the task table is:

```
SELECT
    tasks.*
FROM
    tasks
WHERE
    (
        (
            tasks.description LIKE '%$search%'
            OR tasks. NAME LIKE '$search%'
        )
        AND tasks. USER = '$userid'
    );
```

The way I search the activities table is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    tasks.*
FROM
    activities,
    tasks
WHERE
    tasks. USER = '1'
AND activities.description LIKE '%$search%';
```

The individual queries work and they both return task table data. What I want to do is merge both results (in php) so that I only get all the table tasks entries with no repetition.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not execute two queries and merge using `array_merge()` afterwards? (Other than performance concerns, of course.)

Comment: How do you need them to be combined? If the results from activities and tasks have nothing to do with each other, you can use array_merge. Otherwise you need to loop the returned array and match them (but then you might want to consider a join in SQL)

Comment: This was the way that It ocurred to me. I much prefer an intelligent SQL query solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either execute two queries and merge the results using variant of `array_merge()` afterwards (taking care of possible duplicates), or simply connect the `WHERE` clause in your two `SELECT` statements with an `OR` operator:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT tasks.*
FROM
    activities,
    tasks
WHERE
    (
        (
            tasks.description LIKE '%$search%'
            OR tasks.NAME LIKE '$search%'
        )
        AND tasks.USER = '$userid'
    )
    OR
    (
        tasks.USER = '$userid'
        AND activities.description LIKE '%$search%'
    );
```

Applying some boolean optimizations:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT tasks.*
FROM
    activities,
    tasks
WHERE
    tasks.USER = '$userid'
    AND
    (
        tasks.description LIKE '%$search%'
        OR tasks.NAME LIKE '$search%'
        OR activities.description LIKE '%$search%'
    );
```

Anyway, seeing your code I certainly hope you protect yourself against [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) by [carefully sanitizing your data](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), or use [`PDOStatement::bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) which takes care of that for you.

Comment: Second option Worked!. Cannot believe I didn't see that. Thank you!!. Could you also tell how would it be possible to inject sql code into that? I don't understand. I would completely break the syntax. And, no I'm not usign that command, but I'm a newbie at this.

Comment: See what happens if you type into `$search` a variable which contains `'`, or `');SHOW TABLES;--`. This makes it important to sanitize user input. Proper usage of library like PDO mitigates this kind of security issue altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I still don't understand que sql injection. I wrote 'hola in one (test the first option) and copied and pasted your second suggestion. I got my ERROR in SQL syntax error (I user a closable label to show errors). So, as I expected, the syntax broke.

Comment: Yep. You can use it to do malicious things such as entering search term `'); DROP TABLE activities;--`, which will result in two queries: proper `SELECT ... WHERE (); ` and right after that `DROP TABLE activities;--rest of original query`. `--rest of original query` will be ignored (`--` is used to start a comment). As a result, your `activities` table will be dropped.

Comment: Ok. I understand now. I tried it and did not work (have no Idea why as the query made sense), but the table wasn't dropped. However I get what you are trying to say now. Thank you.